# eclipse debugging 'source no found'

Tags: java, eclipse

There are already several 'Source not found' questions this forum. But none of them is like mine.

I try to debug ftp4j in eclipse and eclipse tells me 'Source not found'. i have already download the jar and source files.

[image]

I have set the source attachement of ftp4j.

[image: Edit Source Lookup Path]
eclipse debugging still need source. I surf here, it seem eclipse need something like junit-4.11-source.jar. if so ,  but there is not ftp4j-1.7.2-source.jar in ftp-1.7.2.zip.

If all my words are not wrong, can i make  ftp4j-1.7.2-source.jar ? and how?

Comment: Have you tried clicking Edit Source Lookup Path and point directly to your source jar?  I've seen eclipse have issues similar to this before.

Comment: *"But none of them is like mine."* No, of course not, because you're ***special!*** LOL  - That comment reads to me like *"I couldn't be bothered searching, so I'll just claim I did and that all the other questions were different."*  A better way to express that you searched is to list the top 3 qns. that seemed related, and explain why they were not relevant.  Else - be mocked..

Comment: @sunrong please post links to where you sourced the jars from. The jar containing, .class files that you are adding to your compile time and runtime class path, and the jar containing .java files, that you are referencing for source.

Comment: @Tinman http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftp4j/files/ftp4j/1.7.2/ftp4j-1.7.2.zip/download ftp4j-1.7.2.zip contains .jar , source files and docs. But source files cannot be added to debug.

Comment: @AndrewThompson 'none of them is like mine' maybe is a arbitrary statement.I spend more than 2 hours searching and reading not only stackoverflow.com but also google.com and baidu.com.  I spend nearly 1 hour wrting my question, My English is not good as you think.So "I couldn't be bothered searching...." is your arbitrary thought. You are very rude. The number of answer to my question is small, I prefer to searching here for I don't know whether what i said is clear enough for person like you to understand what my problem is. And some of the question and answer here is hard for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is going wrong**
The reason your source is not being recognized is because it is in a subfolder called src.

What you want a sources.jar file the same structure as the runtime file, but including the .java files in the same folders as the .class files were in the runtime jar.

Runtime jar

```
/packages/yourclasses.class
/package2/anotherclasses.class
```

Source jar

```
/packages/yourclasses.java
/package2/anotherclasses.java
```

**To create this from the provided zip file,**

- extract the source
- go into the src folder
- create a -sources.jar file

Example command lines for windows with a JDK installed

```
jar xf ftp4j.zip
cd ftp4j-1.7.2\src  
jar cf ftp4j-sources.jar .
```

**A further note**

If you don't have the source code, you can always add a de-compiler to eclipse.

See http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/

If you install this to your eclipse it sometimes helps when you don't have the original source code.

Of course sometimes you can't debug  into the decompiled code, due to line numbers not matching up properly.

Comment: It's a great tools. Thanks for your helping. I will need it someday.This time , it seems i have the entire source files, The pity is it is not a  source.jar file.